# How to save a photo without transparency turning white MS paint

Tags: editing

while editing a photo, I tried to make a transparent window which my computer detects, making a real transparent window. however, I made it and transferred it to the printer and I appeared white, [I use a printer i built myself that prints then cuts holes to put a window in it if detects transparency.] how do i have the photo in .jpeg, .png, or .BMP [bitmap]

Comment: Jpeg doesn't support transparency. Some BMP variants do, but your best bet is PNG.

Comment: @xenoid [Please put your answers in the answers section, even if they're short](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4655/15871) and [Criteria for determining if a post should be a comment or an answer](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5578/15871)

Answer (score 5):

I don't use Windows, but some Googling tells me MS Paint cannot save transparency. (It can apparently open it & use it but discards at save) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Paint

I'd be looking for a different editor. [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org) & [Paint.net](https://www.getpaint.net/) are free.

Comment: Gimp can be a bit overwhelming for a beginner (but worth looking at), but about any bitmap editor is going to be better than MS Paint.

Comment: @xenoid - feel free to edit in specific suggestions if you know of any. Not being a Win user I really don't know what's available.

Comment: Paint.NET is easy, good and free. https://www.getpaint.net/